# Não consigo alterar o rootViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

Olá, tenham calma comigo pois sou extremamente iniciante.

Estou tentando alterar a root de uma aplicação que estou tentando fazer. Até funcionou quando comentei o `window!.rootViewController = centerContainer`

Mas quando faço isso, o menu para de funcionar. Alguém pode me dar um help? Acredito que todo a minha complicação esteja no AppDelegate.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?

var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    _ = self.window!.rootViewController

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)



    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeViewController") as! homeViewController

    let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController

    let rightViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController

    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    let rightNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav,rightDrawerViewController:rightNav)

    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

    window!.rootViewController = centerContainer

    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()






    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PaginaInicial", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())      
let loginView: SignInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInVC") as! SignInVC
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginView
```

Comment: Eu tenho que criar 1 ViewController e um arquivo CocoaTouchClass com nome SignInVCViewController né?

Ai coloco a Class no ViewController e Storyboard ID(SignInVCViewController). 

E coloco o código no AppDelegate.

É isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo.

Comment: Me devolve um SIGABRT na linha 'class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {'

Comment: Não estou tratando duas ViewController diferentes como root?

Comment: tente isso aqui... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316966/how-to-set-the-rootviewcontroller-with-swift-ios-7

Comment: Não consigo, tenho certeza que estou chamando duas roots. :(
Não sei como trabalhar essas três linhas fora da root.

'     let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        let rightNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)'

Comment: cara nao tem erro, eh soh seguir esse tuto, esse codigo dah certo... é só prestar atenção no código e no nome das suas views.

Comment: Definir a root não é problema, o problema é alterar a root usando MMDrawerController.
Estou googlando aqui. Mas está horrível.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38879/discussion-between-leu-oliveira-and-jadson-medeiros).

Comment: Consegui, valeu!